# ChartJS - Data array longer than number of labels?

Tags: javascript, charts, linechart

I am making a line chart for chartjs. I am trying to figure out how/if I can pass in a longer data array than there are labels for. So basically a time series in ChartJS?

Sort of something like: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series

I have something like:

```
    var data = {
labels: [1,2,3],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,]
    }
]
};
```

Where labels 1,2,3 represent hours. I want to be displaying some more fine tuned data than just at one hour (say every minute or so) but not have that be labeled.

Comment: Where you able to find any solution ?